# Passing reference by reference?

Tags: c++, reference

Consider the following code:

```
void func(Thing& thing) {
    ...
}

int main() {
    Thing t;
    Thing& ref = t;
    func(ref);
}
```

I'm passing a reference, by reference.

Is that totally equivalent to the following code?

```
void func(Thing& thing) {
    ...
}

int main() {
    Thing t;
    func(t);
}
```

If not, what exactly is the difference in outcome?

Comment: References are pointers in disguise. The code is equivalent to `void func(Thing *thing)` and `Thing t; Thing *ref = &t; func(t)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Thing t;
Thing& ref = t;
func(ref);

Thing t;
Thing ref = t; // ref is not a reference to t, but a copy of t
func(ref);
```

The difference is that in the first case the original object `t` is passed, in the second case - its copy.

---

After editing of the question, both cases behave the same way.

```
Thing t;
Thing& ref = t;
func(ref);

Thing t;
func(t);
```

Comment: Let me see if I understand: using a reference in an expression is like using a *dereferenced* pointer, correct? I.e. saying `ref` somewhere is like saying `*pointer` somewhere, right? If so, than passing `ref` to the function simply passes the original object, because `func(ref)` is implicitly translated to `func(*ref)` (if `ref` was a pointer)?

Comment: @AvivCohn References are _somewhat_ similar to pointers, but still quite different. Whan you initialize a reference, you create a synonym for the referred object. And then passing the reference should have the same effect as passing the object itself. (Assuming the reference has the same cv-qualifiers.)

Comment: So basically a reference is just another name for the object (kinda)?

Comment: I find "alias" a more natural term than "reference" .. however "reference" has come to be standard

Comment: @MattMcNabb `alias` sounds better, but still could be confusing. The term somehow assumes (IMhO) that no storage is needed for it. While it is true in our case, in principle storage is required when we refer to external entities.

Comment: @AvivCohn _"So basically a reference is just another name for the object (kinda)?"_ Yeah, up to some extent, but you have to stress the last word.

Comment: @MattMcNabb So btw, what exactly does it mean for a function to return `const T&`? If we assign the return value to a normal variable, e.g. `Thing t = func()`, a copy is made, as though the function actually returns `T`. So I would say that the only implication of a function to return const reference, as opposed to returning a standard reference (`T&`), or a standard object (`T`) is that we wouldn't be able to assign the return value to a normal reference. Do you agree with that?

Comment: Returning a reference means that the *return value object* is actually the same object as some other object (and so, it doesn't need destruction or construction, and can't be moved out of, etc.)  This is a new question really (it's more of a corollary to your other question about returning a const reference).  In `Thing t = func();`, `t` is copied or moved from the *return value*.  You could also look up on lvalues. (You can take the address of the return value of a function which returns an lvalue reference; but you can't take the address of a temporary object).

Answer (score 1):

This seems more like a "what are references" question.

You can understand references in terms of objects, and expressions which *identify* those objects. In the case:

```
Thing t;
Thing ref = t;
```

we have two distinct objects. One is known by the name `t` and the other is known as `ref`.

In the case:

```
Thing t;
Thing &ref = t;
```

there is a single object; and it has two identifiers, `t` and `ref`. That code is *exactly the same* as:

```
Thing ref;
Thing &t = ref;
```

Whenever you use `thing` or `ref` in an expression, it is understood to be identifying that single object.

Calling `func` binds a reference to whichever *object* was supplied. In the second case, there is no difference between `func(ref)` and `func(t)`, they both pass the same object. When we are inside `func`, there is still a single object and it has *three* names:

```
main::ref       // not currently visible
main::t         // not currently visible
func::thing     // visible
```

(note: this use of `::` is not valid C++ syntax, hopefully it is clear what I mean). Visibility applies to identifiers, not to objects.

Comment: @AlexD OK I'll remove that sentence, it doesn't really say what I was trying to say anyway